# Attributes not showing up in UITextView (iOS 8/Xcode 6.4)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to load an RTF file and display it's contents inside a UITextView using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = YES;

     NSURL *rtfpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"rtfFile" withExtension:@"rtf"];

     NSAttributedString *rtfText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:rtfpath options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

     self.textView.attributedText = rtfText;
}
```

The text loads fine, but none of the attributes (size, color, bold, font) show up and it just displays the text using a basic system font. This is a relatively large file that will be edited frequently so is there any I way I can display attributes (for example I want the section headings to be bold) without manually hard coding every line of text?

Also I've tried manually pasting the contents of my file into the attributed text field of the UITextView in the storyboard. It actually displays everything with attributes in the storyboard, but when I run the code all my attributes disappear again.

Comment: Does `rtfText` show the attributes?

Comment: Yes, rtfText does show the attributes

Comment: Just not displaying on the UITextView

Comment: Do you somewhere else maybe set `self.textView.text` or `self.textView.attributedText` after your code?

Comment: No not setting the text anywhere else. I just saw that changes in text color are passing through, but the text size and font are not being picked up by the UITextView

Comment: Does the fonts exist inside your app? Custom Font "name" and Size are inside the `NSFontAttributeName`, if your app doesn't find them, that could be the issue. Do you have a "small" example of your rtf causing the issue?